# double free or corruption (!prev) but for sure no double free()

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, dynamic, free

I am getting a `double free or corruption (!prev)` but I do not know why. So far I understand what it will tell me. At least I am not doing a double free but it fails for sure on the `free()` command.

Ok, some code. I have a structure defined as follows:

```
#define OWMINDEV 2

struct owdevice_struct {
        char    name[30];
        float   value;
};

struct ow_struct {
        int     countdev;
        struct owdevice_struct *owdevice;
};

struct ow_struct ow;
```

Initially I assign values and use the `*owdevice` as array and I can access and assign values:

```
ow.countdev = OWMINDEV;
ow.owdevice = malloc( OWMINDEV * sizeof(struct owdevice_struct));

strcpy(ow.owdevice[0].name,"t_abl_i");
ow.owdevice[0].value = 3.5;

strcpy(ow.owdevice[1].name,"t_out");
ow.owdevice[1].value = 1.5;
```

I can easily access and read all these values. Fine so far. Now I have a routine which does some sort of re-assigning these variables with a different count (dynamic array). So my idea is to free up the memory which is pointed to by `ow.owdevice` and do an alloc again with the new number of devices.

```
m = 5;
free(ow.owdevice);
ow.owdevice = NULL;
ow.owdevice = calloc( m, sizeof(struct owdevice_struct));
```

But as soon as the program goes to `free()` I am getting the error. And no, there are really no other `free()` calls anywhere in the code regarding the `ow` variable. As it can not be a double free it appears to be a corruption, right? But why?

Interestingly, the first call of the above code (with a countdev of 3 freeing and allocating to a countdev of 20) works without any issues. Just the second call then causes the error.

Any ideas here, guys?

Thanks in advance!

/KNEBB

Comment: how many is OWMINDEV?

Comment: If you run your program with the tool called `valgrind`, there's a very good chance valgrind will find the mistake right away.

Comment: See above. OWMINDEV is 2. I have never used valgrind before. 

Addition: I tried to discover if it is a corruption as the address in the pointer might get overwritten somehow. But no, before the free() it still points to the same address it got assigned.

Comment: If you're on Linux you can just install valgrind (with apt or yum) and put `valgrind` in front of the command to run your program e.g. `valgrind ./my_program` - very easy and convenient. If you're on Windows I don't think valgrind supports Windows. But I think you're on Linux because of the "double free or corruption" message. Seriously, it's a very useful tool for catching these errors.

Comment: Almost certainly you are writing data past the end of the owdevice array by mistake somewhere. e.g. writing element [3] in an array of 3 elements

Comment: Ok, I installed valgrind. But it does not help at all. 
First, it only reports "errors" as following:
```
==30907== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==30907==    at 0x401B628: memcpy (in /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/ld-2.28.so)
```
Second I have to kill it by `kill -9 $PID`as it does not stop. 
Note: My program is a daemon by default and does not end on its own.

I will check for borders in some `for` calls to see if I can find an error writing past the end.

Comment: I seem to remember that some versions of Linux have that error at the beginning of the program which I guess do not stop anything from working (although someone should probably fix them). See if there is any error in your program. Are you saying it crashes when you run it without valgrind, but with valgrind there is no crash? That is unusual

Comment: Yes, exactly. Using my programm will for sure end in the above error message and crash once I triggered the routine (through mqtt).
With valgrind this does not happen. Valgrind just stays and needs to be killed with -9.

Comment: Not crashing with valgrind is not unusual at all, but in general the error that causes the crash is reported anyway. And it could well be something like 'Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)' which e.g. could cause a memory overflow under certain circumstances

Comment: Hi, thanks to your guys hints I found the source of the error. It was indeed writing after the end of the allocated memory. 
I am going to check my code now why it writes to [21] instead of [20].
Thanks for your hints. So it was not a double free() but writing after...

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found the issue.

I had a function which rearranged the items in the above array. Originally I configured three items to be fixed and skipped this items when rearranging.
Further coding I added another two fixed devices but I forgot to skip these, too. So my code included these in rearrangement and wrote to [20] and [21] instead of [19] max.

It wrote after the allocated memory which caused the error when trying to free().

Thanks for all your hints!